# sqlite multiple table joining...how?

Tags: sqlite, join

I have three tables doodhiya, doodhdata and cashdata.

I am trying to join these and fetch some needed data by this code but not succeed

```
SELECT dname,ddate,dmonth,dyear,dmilk,uid 
FROM doodhiya
   INNER JOIN  doodhiya.dhid = doodhdata.ddhid
   INNER JOIN  doodhdata.dhid = cashdata.uid
WHERE (dname='$mik' AND dmonth='$mikdatem' AND dyear='$mikdatey')
ORDER BY  ddate ASC
```

What I have to do?

Comment: @coeur I've noticed & appreciated you fixing spelling mistakes but now that I see you know how to spell "doodhiya" & "doodhdata" I'm *really* impressed.

Comment: @philipxy Even better, I know the _structure_ of "doodhiya" and "doodhdata": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165113/sqlite-multiple-table-join-with-a-condition

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the table name and the ON keyword in your join

```
SELECT dname,ddate,dmonth,dyear,dmilk,uid 
FROM doodhiya
   INNER JOIN doodhdata ON doodhiya.dhid = doodhdata.ddhid
   INNER JOIN cashdata ON doodhdata.dhid = cashdata.uid
WHERE (dname='$mik' AND dmonth='$mikdatem' AND dyear='$mikdatey')
ORDER BY  ddate ASC
```

A note on this part of the question:

> *Pls suggest me what I have to do*

The syntax for a join is documented in the manual (and millions of SQL references in the web). So the best thing you can do the next time is to first consult the manual and/or a SQL reference.

Comment: @horse i have tried a lot after that posted here...I know may be a little mistake making me upset but till than a solution find its big for me...Thanks for correction....but still not solved.

Comment: @ImranKhan: what exactly do you mean with "still not solved".

Comment: actually....I am using above query in a PHP page....and want to fetch some data from above tables.....I used your correction but still no data I found.

Comment: @ImranKhan: well if "no data is found" then apparently there are no rows satisfying your conditions. I don't do PHP, but is `'$mik'` the correct way to use parameters? You might want to re-phrase your question as apparently it's **not** a syntax problem (and also add the PHP tag)

Comment: I cannot add whole code ....I think because I am new here......but I will add it soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT retailername,
       productname,
       qty,
       stock,
       price,
       discount
FROM   temptablename,
       productmaster,
       retailermaster
WHERE  temptablename.pid = productmaster.productid
       AND temptablename.rid = retailermaster. retailercode
```

Comment: And how does this statement relate to the original question?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT dname,
      ddate,
      dmonth,
       dyear,
      dmilk,
      uid
FROM  doodhdata,
       cashdata
 WHERE  doodhiya.dhid = doodhdata.ddhid
       AND doodhdata.dhid = cashdata.uid
       AND dname='$mik' 
       AND dmonth='$mikdatem' 
      AND dyear='$mikdatey'
ORDER BY  ddate ASC
```

Comment: still no change...no data fe3tch @kanaiya